# How can I customize a Dropdown Button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dropdown

How can I archive this design in Flutter?

I need to customize the dropdown button as the following screenshot:

[image]

How can I set a style for the selected item and another for the unselected one, but without changing the style of the label above the dropdown?

If someone could help it would be amazing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
            PopupMenuButton<MenuItems>(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Text('Show Menu'),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.expand_more,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              onSelected: (MenuItems result) {
                setState(() {
                  selection = result;
                });
              },
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
                  <PopupMenuEntry<MenuItems>>[
                PopupMenuItem<MenuItems>(
                  value: MenuItems.one,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      MenuItems.one == selectedItem
                          ? Row(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  width: 3,
                                  height: 16,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 8,
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                          : Container(),
                      Text(
                        'One',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: (MenuItems.one == selectedItem)
                              ? Colors.red
                              : null,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                PopupMenuItem<MenuItems>(
                  value: MenuItems.two,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      MenuItems.two == selectedItem
                          ? Row(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  width: 3,
                                  height: 16,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 8,
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                          : Container(),
                      Text(
                        'Two',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: (MenuItems.two == selectedItem)
                              ? Colors.red
                              : null,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                PopupMenuItem<MenuItems>(
                  value: MenuItems.three,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      MenuItems.three == selectedItem
                          ? Row(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  width: 3,
                                  height: 16,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 8,
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                          : Container(),
                      Text(
                        'Three',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: (MenuItems.three == selectedItem)
                              ? Colors.red
                              : null,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
```